# Конфликт composer

Tags: php, github, composer

Подскажите как решить проблему конфликта composer, пытаюсь установить пакет

> kornrunner/ethereum-offline-raw-tx

получаю ошибку

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for kornrunner/ethereum-offline-raw-tx ^0.2.3 -> satisfiable by kornrunner/ethereum-offline-raw-tx[0.2.3].
- Conclusion: remove fgrosse/phpasn1 v1.5.4
- Conclusion: don't install fgrosse/phpasn1 v1.5.4
- kornrunner/ethereum-offline-raw-tx 0.2.3 requires kornrunner/secp256k1 ^0.1 -> satisfiable by kornrunner/secp256k1[0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2].
- kornrunner/secp256k1 0.1.0 requires mdanter/ecc ~0.5 -> satisfiable by mdanter/ecc[v0.5.0, v0.5.1, v0.5.2].
- kornrunner/secp256k1 0.1.1 requires mdanter/ecc ~0.5 -> satisfiable by mdanter/ecc[v0.5.0, v0.5.1, v0.5.2].
- kornrunner/secp256k1 0.1.2 requires mdanter/ecc ^0.5 -> satisfiable by mdanter/ecc[v0.5.0, v0.5.1, v0.5.2].
- mdanter/ecc v0.5.0 requires fgrosse/phpasn1 v2.0.x -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.0, 2.0.1, v2.0.2].
- mdanter/ecc v0.5.1 requires fgrosse/phpasn1 ^2.0 -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, v2.0.2, v2.1.1].
- mdanter/ecc v0.5.2 requires fgrosse/phpasn1 ^2.0 -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, v2.0.2, v2.1.1].
- Can only install one of: fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.0, v1.5.4].
- Can only install one of: fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.1, v1.5.4].
- Can only install one of: fgrosse/phpasn1[2.1.0, v1.5.4].
- Can only install one of: fgrosse/phpasn1[v2.0.2, v1.5.4].
- Can only install one of: fgrosse/phpasn1[v2.1.1, v1.5.4].
- Installation request for fgrosse/phpasn1 (locked at v1.5.4) -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[v1.5.4].
```

Выяснил что если удалить пакет **blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk**, все нормально устанавливается и потом при попытке поставить **blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk**, опять получаю ошибки
Из всего этого я понял то что оба пакету нуждаются в одной зависимости, только одному из них нужна версия меньше чем другому...
Кто знает как решить это проблему?

```
    {
  "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
  "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
  "keywords": [
    "yii2",
    "framework",
    "advanced",
    "project template"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "^2.1",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "3.0.*",
    "phpgangsta/googleauthenticator": "dev-master",
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "^2.0",
    "maxwen/yii2-curl": "~1.0",
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.6",
    "react/zmq": "~0.3.0",
    "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "^1.4",
    "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "^1.3",
    "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget": "^1.0",
    "Blockchain/Blockchain": "~1.4",
    "loveorigami/yii2-notification-wrapper": "*",
    "bower-asset/toastr": "^2.1",
    "coinbase/coinbase": "^2.7",
    "troytft/cloud-payments-client": "^0.0.11",
    "noroman/bestchange": "^0.3.0",
    "simplito/elliptic-php": "^1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "codeception/specify": "*",
    "codeception/verify": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
  },
  "extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
      "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
      "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Coinbase\\Wallet\\": "vendor/shked0wn/coinbase-php/src"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы все правильно пишите. Можно попытаться попробывать варианты: 1)попробывать использовать  пакет `blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk` ветки *develop* вместо ветки *master*. 2) форкнуть пакет  `blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk` и поправить в нем для зависимости `fgrosse/phpasn1`  версию, проверить работоспособность тестами.  В случае успеха - подключить указанный форкнутый пакет в ваш проект из локального репозитория.

Comment: @Jigius пробовал сделать вариант 2, но он почему-то все равно подключет тот пакет который не нужно, а что за ветка develop?

Comment: покажите  содержимое composer.json вашего проекта

Comment: @Jigius добавил

Comment: @Jigius так как это сделать?